# What does "pour son côté décalé, comme en dehors du temps" mean

Tags: expressions, traduction

I was translating a text and I just can't get the meaning of this, here goes the full sentence:

> Montmartre est apprécié encore aujourd'hui par les Parisiens comme par les touristes, **pour son côté décalé,** **comme en dehors du temps**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Décalé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cal%C3%A9), comme en dehors du temps* means that Montmartre neighborhood is offbeat, i.e. when people are here, they do not feel like being in the 21st century but in a location disconnected from the current time.